# Android - When opening activity the opener disappear before the transition animation ends

Tags: android

I strat an activity like so:

```
new Thread() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Intent i = new Intent();
        i.setClass(getBaseContext(), newPage.class);
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        getBaseContext().startActivity(i);
    }
}.start();
```

and i use `getActivity().overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_from_bottom, R.anim.nothing);`

and in newPage.class i use `overridePendingTransition(R.anim.nothing, R.anim.slide_out_to_bottom);`

the animations are:
slide_in_from_bottom.xml

```
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
           android:fromYDelta="100%p"
           android:toYDelta="0%p"
           android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"/>
```

slide_out_to_bottom.xml

```
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
           android:fromYDelta="0%p"
           android:toYDelta="100%p"
           android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"/>
```

nothing.xml

```
<alpha xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="0" android:fromAlpha="1" android:toAlpha="1"/>
```

**So what's worng?**

when I finish newPage.class it looks great,
but when I start newPage.class - the activity disappear (black screen) and only then the animation of the new activity starts [and i want to keep the first activity on the screen until the new one covers it]

**
tried `getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(null);`

and

```
ColorDrawable colorDrawable = new ColorDrawable( Color.TRANSPARENT );
getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable( colorDrawable );
```

but no luck...